# Prevent toolbaritem icon center in iOS at Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I define a icon in Toolbaritems it show very good in Android on right but in iOS it show icon in ther Center of ther Navigation bar.

How I can put Icon on left same at Android.

Sorry for my poor English.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Back" Order="Primary" IconImageSource="icon_delete_400.png" Clicked="OnBack" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Android Show Right (Nice)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LJfx.jpg)

iOS show Center (Not good)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ5aN.png)

Github (Sample Source): https://github.com/westermost/Study-Xamarin

Comment: Left or right? The icon in the picture you shared is on the right side while you say it is left in the question.

Comment: I wanna it on right. In Android it working nice. But in iOS it on Center and I wanna it on right same at Android

Comment: I just use your code and default  behavior of ContentPage.ToolbarItems is on the right on iOS. Can you share a sample with this problem?

Comment: Thanks for help. I had been update my Github link. Hope you can help me.

Comment: I added an answer below and you can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running your project, I find the cause of your problem is the size of your image is too big(`160*160`) and it takes half area of the `navigationBar`, so it looks like stay in the center in your screenshot.

If you give a proper size of the image, it will show at the right side as your expected. I resize the image to 40* 40 and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

Put toolbar item like this

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
   <ToolbarItem Name="iconexample" Icon="icon_delete_400.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" Clicked="OnBack" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

In ios  place the image at /mipmap/icon_delete_400.png

In Android place the image at /mipmap/drawable/icon.png

Comment: Thanks for help. But it not working. You can see it by my picture has upload.